# Need approach on building Custom NER for extracting below keywords from any format of payslips

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to build a generic extraction of below parameters from any format of payslip:

1. Name
2. His PostCode
3. Pay Date
4. Net Pay.

Challenge I am facing is due to variety of format that may come, I want to apply NER (Spacy) to learn these under the entities

1. Name - PERSON
2. His PostCode
3. Pay Date - DATE
4. Net Pay. - MONEY

But I am unsuccess so far, I even tried to build a custom EntityMatcher for Postcode & Date but to no success.

I seek any guideline and approach to make me take the right path in achieving the above ask, as to what is the right and best approach under the ML to achieve this.

A snippet of Custom NER I tried to build

```
import spacy
import random
import threading
import time
from DateEntityMatcher import  DateEntityMatcher
from PostCodeEntityMatcher import PostCodeEntityMatcher


class IncomeValidatorModel(object):
    """ Threading example class
    The run() method will be started and it will run in the background
    until the application exits.
    """

    def __init__(self, interval=1):
        """ Constructor
        :type interval: int
        :param interval: Check interval, in seconds
        """
        self.interval = interval

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True                            # Daemonize thread
        thread.start()                                  # Start the execution

    def run(self):
        """ Method that runs forever """
        while True:
            # Do something
            print('Doing something important in the background')
            DATA = [
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR K KHANA    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M MENON    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR F JAHAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR A JAHAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
                {'entities': [(203, 218, 'ORG'), (100, 106, 'PERSON'), (1097, 1103, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Sample Payslip    Matrix House    Basing View    Basingstoke    Hampshire    RG21 4FF    Advantage Resourcing    6th Floor, Matrix House, Basing View, Basingstoke, Hampshire, RG21 4FF    Registered Number 03341461    COMPANY    DIVISION    Advantage Resourcing UK    SWINDON    WORKER NO.    NAME    PERIOD    PAY DATE    IND    123456    Sample Payslip    14/2016    08/07/2016    W1    DEPARTMENT    TAX CODE    N.I. NO./TABLE LETTER    NAT    1100L    JA123456A/A    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    Wk Ending    Timesheet    Description    Units    Rate    Amount    Deduction    Amount    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Hourly Rate    40.00    10.00    400.00    Tax    87.60    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Week Day Overtime    10.00    15.00    150.00    NI    59.40    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Saturday Overtime    5.00    20.00    100.00    TOTAL PAYMENTS    650.00    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    147.00    CUMULATIVES    GROSS TO DATE    650.00    Current Holiday Entitlement: 0.00 Unit(s)    TAXABLE PAY TO DATE    650.00    EE PENSION TO DATE    0.00    ER PENSION TO DATE    0.00    TAX TO DATE    87.60     TO DATE    68.17    TO DATE    59.40    c Safe Computing Limited 2002    NET PAY    503.00",
                {'entities': [(89, 109, 'ORG'), (0, 14, 'PERSON'), (1186, 1191, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Mubssar Hasan    Matrix House    Basing View    Basingstoke    Hampshire    RG21 4FF    Advantage Resourcing    6th Floor, Matrix House, Basing View, Basingstoke, Hampshire, RG21 4FF    Registered Number 03341461    COMPANY    DIVISION    Advantage Resourcing UK    SWINDON    WORKER NO.    NAME    PERIOD    PAY DATE    IND    123456    Sample Payslip    14/2016    08/07/2016    W1    DEPARTMENT    TAX CODE    N.I. NO./TABLE LETTER    NAT    1100L    JA123456A/A    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    Wk Ending    Timesheet    Description    Units    Rate    Amount    Deduction    Amount    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Hourly Rate    40.00    10.00    400.00    Tax    87.60    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Week Day Overtime    10.00    15.00    150.00    NI    59.40    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Saturday Overtime    5.00    20.00    100.00    TOTAL PAYMENTS    650.00    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    147.00    CUMULATIVES    GROSS TO DATE    650.00    Current Holiday Entitlement: 0.00 Unit(s)    TAXABLE PAY TO DATE    650.00    EE PENSION TO DATE    0.00    ER PENSION TO DATE    0.00    TAX TO DATE    87.60     TO DATE    68.17     TO DATE    59.40    c Safe Computing Limited 2002    NET PAY    503.00",
                {'entities': [(88, 108, 'ORG'), (0, 13, 'PERSON'), (1186, 1191, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Oracle Corp Anil Menon Work Date 01/09/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 2000",
                 {'entities': [(0, 10, 'ORG'), (12, 21, 'PERSON'), (69, 72, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Huawei Corp Anil Menon Work Date 01/06/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1900",
                 {'entities': [(0, 10, 'ORG'), (12, 21, 'PERSON'), (69, 72, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Tata Corp Nitin Garg Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1900",
                 {'entities': [(0, 8, 'ORG'), (10, 19, 'PERSON'), (67, 70, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Accenture Corp Amol Joshi Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 900",
                 {'entities': [(0, 15, 'ORG'), (17, 26, 'PERSON'), (72, 74, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Cognizant Corp Anup Nair Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 900",
                 {'entities': [(0, 15, 'ORG'), (17, 25, 'PERSON'), (71, 73, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Cognizant Corp Sajit Kumar Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1900",
                 {'entities': [(0, 15, 'ORG'), (17, 27, 'PERSON'), (73, 76, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Tata Corp Saurabh Dave Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1300",
                 {'entities': [(0, 8, 'ORG'), (10, 21, 'PERSON'), (69, 72, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Capgemini PLC Mubashshir Hasan Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1700",
                 {'entities': [(0, 12, 'ORG'), (14, 29, 'PERSON'), (77, 80, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Capgemini PLC Sagar Pande Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 1700",
                 {'entities': [(0, 12, 'ORG'), (14, 24, 'PERSON'), (72, 75, 'MONEY')]}),
                (u"Capgemini PLC Sreeram Yegappan Work Date 20/04/2019 PAYMENTS Tax 100 Net Pay 2000",
                 {'entities': [(0, 12, 'ORG'), (14, 29, 'PERSON'), (77, 80, 'MONEY')]})
            ]

            # nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # new, empty model. Let’s say it’s for the English language
            global nlp
            nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
            nlp.entity.add_label('ORG')
            nlp.entity.add_label('PERSON')
            nlp.entity.add_label('MONEY')

            # add NER pipeline
            # ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')  # our pipeline would just do NER
            # nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)  # we add the pipeline to the model
            postcde_entity_matcher = PostCodeEntityMatcher(nlp, ['NN1 3LE', 'NN2 8HF', 'IG3 8TH', 'NN4 7YH', 'RG21 5GH'], 'POSTCDE')
            nlp.entity.add_label('POSTCDE')
            nlp.add_pipe(postcde_entity_matcher, before='ner')

            date_entity_matcher = DateEntityMatcher(nlp, ['20/04/2019','20/04/2019', '25/04/2016', '20/04/2019', '20/07/2019', '20/12/2019'], 'DATE')
            nlp.entity.add_label('DATE')
            nlp.add_pipe(date_entity_matcher, before='ner')

            optimizer = nlp.begin_training()

            for i in range(11):
                random.shuffle(DATA)
                for text, annotations in DATA:
                    nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)

            time.sleep(self.interval)

    def extractPayslipData(self, data):
        doc = nlp(data)
        for entity in doc.ents:
            print(entity.label_, ' | ', entity.text)
        return doc.ents
```

Comment: Does your data follow the same patter always?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: In extractPayslipData(), what do you get as output from one of the lines you mentioned in the training data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Training json(x.json) should be like this:-**

```
[{
    "text": "PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53",
    "entities": [
        [
            191,
            198,
            "PERSON"
        ],
        [
            202,
            211,
            "ORG"
        ],
        [
            150,
            157,
            "POST_CODE"
        ],
        [
            1096,
            1103,
            "MONEY"
        ]]
},
{
    "text": "Mubssar Hasan    Matrix House    Basing View    Basingstoke    Hampshire    RG21 4FF    Advantage Resourcing    6th Floor, Matrix House, Basing View, Basingstoke, Hampshire, RG21 4FF    Registered Number 03341461    COMPANY    DIVISION    Advantage Resourcing UK    SWINDON    WORKER NO.    NAME    PERIOD    PAY DATE    IND    123456    Sample Payslip    14/2016    08/07/2016    W1    DEPARTMENT    TAX CODE    N.I. NO./TABLE LETTER    NAT    1100L    JA123456A/A    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    Wk Ending    Timesheet    Description    Units    Rate    Amount    Deduction    Amount    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Hourly Rate    40.00    10.00    400.00    Tax    87.60    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Week Day Overtime    10.00    15.00    150.00    NI    59.40    03/07/2016    GEN000499628 Saturday Overtime    5.00    20.00    100.00    TOTAL PAYMENTS    650.00    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    147.00    CUMULATIVES    GROSS TO DATE    650.00    Current Holiday Entitlement: 0.00 Unit(s)    TAXABLE PAY TO DATE    650.00    EE PENSION TO DATE    0.00    ER PENSION TO DATE    0.00    TAX TO DATE    87.60     TO DATE    68.17     TO DATE    59.40    c Safe Computing Limited 2002    NET PAY    503.00",
    "entities": [
        [
            1,
            13,
            "PERSON"
        ],
        [
            88,
            108,
            "ORG"
        ],
        [
            150,
            157,
            "POST_CODE"
        ],
        [
            1186,
            1192,
            "MONEY"
        ]]
}

]
```

**code:-**

```
with open(training_pickel_file) as input:
TRAIN_DATA = json.load(input)

def main(model=None, output_dir="/home/NLP/model", n_iter=50):
    if model is not None:
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank('en')  # create blank Language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")

    if 'ner' not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe('ner')
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last=True)
    # otherwise, get it so we can add labels
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')

        for annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
            for ent in annotations["entities"]:
                ner.add_label(ent[2])
        print(ner)
        other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']
        with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # only train NER
            optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
            for itn in range(n_iter):
                random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
                losses = {}
                for a in TRAIN_DATA:`
                    doc = nlp.make_doc(a["text"])
                    gold = GoldParse(doc, entities = a["entities"])
                    nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop =0.5, sgd=optimizer, losses = losses)
                print('Losses', losses)
           if output_dir is not None:
               output_dir = Path(output_dir)
               if not output_dir.exists():
                   output_dir.mkdir()
               nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
```

**Model Testing :-**

```
sen = ["""PRIVATE & CONFIDENTIAL    REF. No.    DEPT    SITE    PAY DATE    82521    002    31/07/2019    MR M HASAN    69 ALCOMBE ROAD    NORTHAMPTON    UK    NN1 3LE    CONFIDENTIAL PAY ADVICE    MR M HASAN    CAPGEMINI UK PLC    EMP REFERENCE    COME A TAXDISTRICT    TAXREFERENCE    D83/82521    475/VB53759    TAXABLE PAY    14297.14    AY DATE    31/07/2019    TAX PERIOD    2019-04    ANN. SALARY    49650.00    TAX PAID    1611.40    PAY METHOD    BACS    TAX CODE    1871L    PAY PERIOD    MONTHLY    N.I. EMPLOYEE    1365.96    N.I. NUMBER    SY095026C    CONTRACT HRS    40.00    PERIOD PAY    4137.50    N.I. EMPLOYER    1576.11    N.I. TABLE    A    O/TIME RATE    23.8702    HOURLY RATE    23.8702    PAYMENTS    DEDUCTIONS    DESCRIPTION    HRS/UNITS    RATE    VALUE    TO DATE    DESCRIPTION    VALUE    BAL ANCE    TO DATE    BENEFIT ALLOW    620.67    706.61    NAT.INS    385.84    1365.96    DISP NT    -353.08    -1253.08    P.A.Y.E.    474.80    1611.40    SALARY    4137.50    16514.38    ACCOM NT    -470.77    -1670.77    GROSS PAY    4758.17    TOTAL DEDUCTIONS    860.64    NET PAY    3897.53"""]
for text in sen:
    doc = nlp(text)
    entity = {}
    for ent in doc.ents:
        list_of_ent = []
        list_of_ent.append(ent.text)
        entity.update({ent.label_: list_of_ent})
    print(entity)
```

**Result :-**
[image]

Comment: what does "for text in sen:" signifies here? Is it tokenizing words from sentence?

Comment: You can add more training data in json for better accuracy, It is for iterating words from sen.